# How to duplicate input to child input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to copy text from input to its own input. Because I have a number of them waiting.

For example :  `src1` to `dest1` ,`src2` to `dest2` ...`src5` to `dest5`

I don't want to pair them with IDs so I wrote:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $src = $('.src'), //source value
    $dst = $src.attr('data-dest'); //destination id from .src data-dest
  $src.on('input', function() {
    $dst.val($src.val()); //text from .src will be here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type='text' class='src' data-dest="dest1"> Dest 1: <input type='text' id='dest1' readonly>
<br /> Src 2: <input type='text' class='src' data-dest="dest2"> Dest 2: <input type='text' id='dest2' readonly>
```

But it's not working as expect. JS here : http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/vsz7bt5L/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `$dst` is a string holding the value in the `data` attribute, not a jQuery object, hence you cannot call `val()` on it. To fix this you need to use the `$dst` value as an id selector in a jQuery object.

The secondary issue is that you're selecting a single data attribute from the first `.src` element, not the one which was clicked. To fix this you need to move that logic inside the click handler and use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the `input` event. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    var $src = $(this);
    var dst = $src.data('dest');
    $('#' + dst).val($src.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest1"> 
Dest 1: <input type="text" id="dest1" readonly><br />

Src 2: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest2"> 
Dest 2: <input type="text" id="dest2" readonly>
```

Comment: Hi @Wilf I noticed you removed the accepted answer - was there a problem with implementing the above? Anything I can help with?

Comment: Sorry, I run the snippet and test again with your answer here. It's not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what doesn't work? Without seeing your broken code I can't really help you debug it. Could you also check the console for errors and let me know what they are

Answer (score 1):

Simply trigger like this:

HTML:

```
Src 1: <input type='text' class='src' data-dest="dest1">
Dest 1: <input type='text' id='dest1' readonly>
<br />
Src 2: <input type='text' class='src' data-dest="dest2">
Dest 2: <input type='text' id='dest2' readonly>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    $($(this).attr('#' + 'data-dest')).val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please bind blur function to source input .
I created that functionality

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $src = $('.src');
  $src.on('blur', function() {
   var dest = $(this).attr('data-dest');
    var $dst=$("#"+dest);
    $dst.val($(this).val());
    $dst.attr("data-dest",val);
  });
});
```

you can see a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/6bg92ept/)

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use `next()`, so no need to hassle around id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.src').on('input', function() {
    let $src = $(this);
    $src.next().val($src.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Src 1: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest1"> 
Dest 1: <input type="text" id="dest1" readonly><br /> 
Src 2: <input type="text" class="src" data-dest="dest2"> 
Dest 2: <input type="text" id="dest2" readonly>
```